# How to update an env variable value with python on debian?

Tags: python, environment-variables, debian

I want to update the value of an environment variable in python, on a debian machine and below is my code:

```
import os

os.environ[command[1]] = command[2]
```

command[1] is my variable name and I'm assigning a value command[2] to it. But this piece of code does not appear to be updating the value when I echo $Var.
How do I make it fix this and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Environment variables are specific to the process. You cannot update environment variables of another process in your process.

Comment: Do you mean the change is not visible *outside* the Python process? A process *cannot* alter the environment of another. The sole exception is that a process receives a *copy* of its parent's environment at startup. No change made by the child will be visible to the parent, and the parent cannot make any changes after providing the initial environment.

Comment: Are u trying to update the machine env variable? 
Python os.environ is affecting only your program env.

Comment: Thanks, Aplet123, chepner, Avihay Tsayeg! Is there a way I can write the values to a specific file where they are stored in, specific to the process?